# Disabling Tinymce toolbars oninit

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using Tinymce 4x with modern theme. I allow to persons to have the same copy of this editor 
    but allowing just one of them to edit it. I need to disable the tinymce toolbar to prevent one of 
    these users to go through them. My editor toolbars when I initialized the editor look like:

```
toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter 
alignright alignjustify ",
toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquoter",
toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript |charmap emoticons|print fullscreen "

I need to disable toolbar1, toolbar2 and toolbar3 and I try to use :

/*tinymce.ui.toolbar1.setDisabled = true; for all these bars but it does not work. It seems that
this is only used for the user created toolbars. 

Also I tried to add listener and then stop the propagation when the toolbar is clicked but also 
it doesn't work

toolbarElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        });
        toolbarElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        }

Please can someone help me. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable above `<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>` which determine `toolbar1:` value's. `"null"` can filled by anything that not in TinyMCE toolbar  name's.

```
<script>
var tbSet1 = "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify";
if(true){tbSet1 = "null";}
var tbSet2 = "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent"; blockquoter";
if(true){tbSet2 = "null";}
var tbSet3 = "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript |charmap emoticons|print fullscreen ";
if(true){tbSet3 = "null";}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

tinymce.init({
    toolbar1: tbSet1 ,
    toolbar2: tbSet2 ,
    toolbar3: tbSet3
```

CMIIW

Comment: Thanks for your answer 'Panji' but it doesn't work because when I initialize the editor it takes the null value and assign it to toolbar. I need to change this when I have oninit event not when init event :/